# Image not able to scrape in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, axios, puppeteer

I am trying to save all image available in the entire webpage when loaded, I am using puppeteer to scrape the data , but when I try to scrape the image and save it to folder only the URL is being printed in the console and no image is downloaded

```
    let aa = await page.$$('img[src]');
    let arr = [];
  
    for (let i of aa) {
      let evawl = await page.evaluate((el) => el.getAttribute('src'), i);
      arr.push(evawl);
      console.log(evawl);
    }
  
    
    let folderpath = path.join(__dirname, 'img');
    try {
       fs.mkdir(folderpath);
    } catch (err) {
      
      if (err.code !== 'EEXIST') {
        throw err;
      }
    }
  
    for (let imageUrl of arr) {
      try {
        let imageResponse = await axios.get(imageUrl, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });
        let imageName = imageUrl.split('/').pop();
        let imagePath = path.join(folderpath, imageName);
        fs.writeFileSync(imagePath, imageResponse.data);
        console.log(`Downloaded: ${imageUrl}`);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(`Error downloading ${imageUrl}: ${err.message}`);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide resource, you're trying to scrap? Your code works fine on random site with images.

Comment: [l Was trying to scape this](https://books.toscrape.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not getting image, because href contains only url part, like `media/cache/2c/da/2cdad67c44b002e7ead0cc35693c0e8b.jpg`, so by accessing it no data can be received.

To resolve this issue, you should add base URL to `axios.get`.

```js
const url = "https://books.toscrape.com/";

// your code

let imageResponse = await axios.get(`${url}${imageUrl}`, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'});

// your other code
```

Comment: thanks, it works  you were right , without adding the base url it was only extracting the link